# Commit .git folder from subfolder in git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

Below is structure of git repository which has another git repository initialized using `git init` in subfolder `dir`.

```
$ tree -a -L 2 . 
.
├── .git
│   ├── HEAD
│   ├── config
│   ├── description
│   ├── hooks
│   ├── info
│   ├── objects
│   └── refs
└── dir
    └── .git
```

How to commit and push `.git` folder from the subfolder?

I tried running `git add dir/.git` and `git commit ..`, but nothing was commited as far as `git log` is concerned.

Repository inside `dir` is used in deployment by some tool which needs to clone/checkout changes from local git repository in `dir`.

Comment: Could this be an XY problem and you're actually looking for git submodules?

Comment: You have to use `git submodules`

Comment: You cannot clone a project inside another. You should rely on submodules or subtree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using git submodules according to [tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) helped.

Below sequence of commands illustrates the required test flow:

```
$ mkdir git_repo
$ cd git_repo/
$:git_repo  git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/git_repo/.git/
$:git_repo  mkdir inner_repo
$:git_repo  cd inner_repo
$:inner_repo  git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/git_repo/inner_repo/.git/
$:inner_repo  touch file
$:inner_repo  git add file
$:inner_repo  git commit -m 'initial'
[master (root-commit) 2b13943] initial
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
$:inner_repo  cd ..
$:git_repo  git submodule add ./inner_repo
Adding existing repo at 'inner_repo' to the index
$:git_repo  cd ..
$ git clone git_repo/inner_repo inner
Cloning into 'inner'...
done.
```

Below flow achieved the desired result in existing local repository which had remote in Bitbucket:

- create folder for inner repository in parent repository
- copy some files to `inner_repo`
- initialize inner repository and commit the files (inside `inner_repo` run `git init` and `git commit -am 'initial'`)
- go to parent repo: `cd ..`.
- critical step: `git submodule add ./inner_repo ./inner_repo`

After that `.gitmodules` and `inner_repo` were staged.

Explanation according to [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt):

`git submodule add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--depth <depth>] [--] <repository> [<path>]`

> Add the given repository as a submodule at the given path to the
> changeset to be committed next to the current project: the current
> project is termed the "superproject".

> The optional argument `<path>` is the relative location for the cloned submodule to exist in the superproject. If `<path>` exists and is already a valid Git repository, then it is
> staged for commit without cloning.